# SQL - How to ignore insert of duplicate data (UNIQUE) if it's an empty string ('')?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, unique, string

My table cadastro:

```
cod_bolsa VARCHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY
nome VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL
endereco VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
telefone VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL
celular VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL
cpf VARCHAR(14) UNIQUE
cnpj VARCHAR(18) UNIQUE
rg VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
datanasc VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
```

---

The query:

```
INSERT INTO cadastro VALUES(
'000036',
'JULIO CESAR',
'AV. FRANZ VOEGELI, 300 - VILA YARA, SÃO PAULO/SP',
'julio.c@mail.com',
'(11)2345-6789',
'(11)99876-5432',
'987.654.321.00',
'',
'98.765.432-1',
'1972-5-12'
);


INSERT INTO cadastro VALUES(
'000125',
'JOAO MARIA',
'AV. FRANZ VOEGELI, 300 - VILA YARA, SÃO PAULO/SP',
'joao.m@mail.com',
'(11)2345-6789',
'(11)91676-1334',
'012.234.567-89',
'',
'01.234.345-8',
'1991-1-20'
);
```

---

MySQL obviously says

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'cnpj'
```

How it could be avoided?

Comment: Can you use `NULL` instead of empty string? [MySQL allows multiple rows with `NULL` in a unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html)

Comment: But these fields must be unique. They're identification numbers.

Comment: then make them unique nullable, and change the `''` to `null` instead. Empty strings (`''`) **ARE** strings, and with a unique index, you can't have more than one record with an empty string in that field.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...`

Comment: Thanks, Martin Smith. It works with NULL. :-)

Comment: IGNORE prohibits adding a new tuple if these values are duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way of "solving" this problem would of course be to make the field non-unique.

But maybe, you want to have something like "if the unique constraint is violated, update the previous entry with something else".

In this case, you might want to use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" or "REPLACE INTO", which are [both explained here](http://thomashunter.name/blog/mysql-replace-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update/).

Comment: INSERT INTO cadastro VALUES(...) ON DUPLICATE KEY set cnpj=null; .  Then when you query: select coalesce(cnpj,'') from cadastro... .

Comment: It can't be updated to something else.

The aim is to register new clients, but they can be people or enterprise, so there are three possible options for the ID number (two for people, and one for enterprises (VATIN)). I'll insert some people first, so obviously they won't have a VATIN. It must be empty or NULL. NULL did the trick, but I don't know if my Java application will be able to transform an empty string (when inserting data via JTextField) to a NULL value into the database. If it's possible, then my question got answered. :-)

Comment: Consider applying a unique key over multiple fields that represent your application logic.

Comment: I got an idea: removing cnpj field from this table and doing another table only for registering enterprises. Or, a table only for registering the cnpj field in case the client is an enterprise; then I could select data from both tables with a LEFT OUTER JOIN; LEFT because if there would be no corresponding cod_bolsa entry in the "cnpj table", it wouldn't be displayed in my application's JTable. Right?

Comment: What would be the difference between applying UNIQUE separately and applying it over multiple fields at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Your table  have a UNIQUE constrain on `[cnpj VARCHAR(18)]`; UNIQUE constrain guarantees uniqueness for cnpj column so you can't insert 2 records have the same cnpj value.